# How can I change popup menu clicked text ripple effect, previously selected text, backgroung colors, itembackground colors according to theme?

Tags: android

Please note: I've searched on google & stackoverflow and **tried in my code**, but solutions not working in my case, that's why asking here,

**What I tried:**

1. android:itemBackground
2. android:textcolor
3. android:popupmenustyle
4. tried different parent in popup style
5. tried programatically

**Requirement:**

1. when I click on item, ripple effect should come according to day and night theme.
2. change color previously selected item text according to theme.
3. change color previously selected item text background according to theme.

**code (working code):**

```
public void showPopup(View view) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(SearchActivity.this, view, R.style.PopupMenu);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.show();
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.all:
                typeId = ALL;
                break;
            case R.id.home:
                typeId = HOME;

                break;
            case R.id.office:
                typeId = OFFICE;
                break;
            case R.id.other:
                typeId = OTHER;
                break;
        }

        searchText.getText().clear();
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        loadAllReminders();

        return false;
    }
```

**style** (*this popupbackground is only working, other things like itembackground or textcolor is not working*):

```
 <style name="PopupMenu" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">?attr/backgroundcolor1</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: You can always create your own layout and show it using PopupWindow.

Comment: @Piyush ummm, N wt abt ur answers?

Comment: @Ikazuchi can you please post an answer?